# Number of line limit in Internet explorer via css

Tags: html, css, sapui5

I already have gone through the all of the solutions previously given to various PFs to limit the number of the line for text in the **Internet Explorer**, but no luck so far:

```css
.sapMTextMaxLine {text-overflow: ellipsis!important; -webkit-line-clamp: 2!important;}
```

```html
<div class="OneByOne sapMGTHdrContent">
  <div class="sapMGTHdrTxt" id="__tile85-hdr-text">
       <span id="__tile85-title" data-sap-ui="__tile85-title" class="sapMGTTitle sapMText sapMTextMaxWidth sapUiSelectable" style="text-align:left">
          <span id="__tile85-title-inner" class="sapMTextLineClamp sapMTextMaxLine" style="-webkit-line-clamp:2">
             My name is Parth and I live in Mumbai, India since last many years
          </span>
       </span>
  </div>
  <div class="sapMGTSubHdrTxt" id="__tile85-subHdr-text">Some Other Info.</div>
</div>
```

Here is the image which shows the text cut problem:

[image]

**How to fix this?**

Comment: You need to provide more code. The text "hiding" on your image is not in your code.

Comment: So you want to truncate the text after 2 lines or not ?

Comment: yes. I also want to show "..." dots in second line end.

Comment: Did you try [Multi-Line Ellipsis in Pure CSS](http://dev.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/)?

Comment: I have gone through it, but implementing same in my app is little difficult as I am using all inbuilt controls and class from SAPUI5.

Comment: Kindly share the complete code to analysis the issue.